# how find position of CAlayer during animation?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am implementing game application.In which i am using layer for animation.

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, previousValuex, previousValue);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, valuex, value);
previousValue=value;
previousValuex=valuex;

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation;
animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.path = path;
animation.duration =1.0;
animation.repeatCount = 0;
//animation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAutoReverse;
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;

// Create a new layer for the animation to run in.
CALayer *moveLayer = [imgObject layer];
[moveLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Now i want to find layer position during animation?Is it possibel?please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried to do this, but you should be able to (perhaps via KVO?) monitor the CALayer's `frame` property (or `position`, or `bounds`, or `anchorPoint`, depending on what you need) during the animation.

Comment: Actually, this won't work in this case.  While you can observe the layer's properties, they only reflect the start or ending values for the layer, not anything in between.  As I clarify in my answer, you will need to look to the presentationLayer for current values of the layer while it is animating.

Comment: Ahh, I see (as I noted, I'd never tried what I was suggesting!). For what it's worth, I've up-voted your answer. It's good to know in case I need to do something like that in the future.

Answer (score 24):

In order to find the current position during an animation, you will need to look at the properties of the layer's `presentationLayer`.  The properties of the layer itself will only reflect the final target value for an implicit animation, or the initial value before you applied the `CABasicAnimation`.  The `presentationLayer` gives you the instantaneous value of whatever property you are animating.

For example,

```
CGPoint currentPosition = [[moveLayer presentationLayer] position];
```

will get you the current position of the layer as it is animating about your path.  Unfortunately, I believe it is difficult to use key-value observing with the presentation layer, so you may need to manually poll this value if you want to track it.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how one would get the **scale** of the presentationLayer?

`[[presentationLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue]` returns the final value (rather than the current).

Answer (score 0):

If your CALayer is inside another CALayer you may need to apply the affineTransform of the parent CALayer to get the position of the child CALayer like this:

```
// Create your layers
CALayer *child = CALayer.layer;
CALayer *parent = self.view.layer;
[parent addSubLayer:child];

// Apply animations, transforms etc...

// Child center relative to parent
CGPoint childPosition = ((CALayer *)child.presentationLayer).position;

// Parent center relative to UIView
CGPoint parentPosition = ((CALayer *)parent.presentationLayer).position;
CGPoint parentCenter = CGPointMake(parent.bounds.size.width/2.0, parent.bounds.size.height /2.0);

// Child center relative to parent center
CGPoint relativePos = CGPointMake(childPosition.x - parentCenter.x, childPosition.y - parentCenter.y);

// Transformed child position based on parent's transform (rotations, scale etc)
CGPoint transformedChildPos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(relativePos, ((CALayer *)parent.presentationLayer).affineTransform);

// And finally...
CGPoint positionInView = CGPointMake(parentPosition.x +transformedChildPos.x, parentPosition.y + transformedChildPos.y);
```

This code is based on code I just wrote in which the parent CALayer was rotating and the position was changing and I wanted to get the position of a child CALayer relative to a touch position in the UIView the parent belonged to.  So this is the basic idea, but I haven't actually run this pseudocode version.