# Display the y value of a uiImageView during an animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have the following code:

```
 NSString *yValue; 


yValue=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%1.2f" , imageView.center.y];


CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake( 10, 100, 200, 50 );
UILabel* label5 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
[label5 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[label5 setText: yValue];
[label5 setTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
  [self.view addSubview: label5];
```

This correctly shows the y value of the UIimageView but the problem is that it only shows the ending y value.

When a person flicks the UIImageView I animate it using:

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut        animations:^{ recognizer.view.center = finalPoint; }
```

What I want is the label5 to display the y value of the imageView during the animation not just after. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That is not possible. The position of the object is not updated while it is in motion. Once it goes into motion, its position values are set to the final position.

Comment: ok, I guess I could probably make a fake counter that adds 1.0 to label5 every .01 seconds until it reaches imageView.center.y

Comment: You could move it with other technologies (OpenGL) which would be able to report back the proper location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how find position of CAlayer during animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932018/how-find-position-of-calayer-during-animation)

Comment: @user1422132 check Brad Larson's answer in linked question. You can get current position via presentationLayer property of view layer. Also as it can't be observed via KVO you'll probably have to use NSTimer to poll layer position